# I tried to make a code that takes a letter as input and gives an array of countries that stars with that letter(JS)

Tags: javascript, loops

so..
i tried to make this function work.I was expecting it to give an array with more than one name but it always says 'Afghanistan'(the first match).
it's supposed to give an array of many different countries' names but it only gives one.I also tried changing the loop from  a 'for of loop' to a 'for' but it didn't work either

here is the funtion:
[country] is an array of 204 countries' names

```js
var country = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cruise Ship", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Satellite", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts &amp; Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "St. Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor L'Este", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad &amp; Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks &amp; Caicos", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (US)", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];


function countrycheck(letter) {

  let counrtieswithA = []
  for (let e of country) {
    let firstletter = e[0]
    if (firstletter === letter) {
      counrtieswithA.push(e)
    }
    return counrtieswithA
  }
}
console.log(countrycheck('A'))
```

Comment: Your return is in the wrong spot!!! Read the code out loud to yourself. Put the return outside the loop.

Comment: A modern day approach would be to use filter.

Answer (score 2):

A return statement will exit the current function - you are currently exiting after the loop’s first iteration.

Instead, you should return after the loop is complete.

Answer (score 0):

When you you call `return` inside a function, you are instructing the interpreter to terminate execution of the function. You should call the `return` statement after the loop is done:

```js
var country = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cruise Ship", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Satellite", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts &amp; Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "St. Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor L'Este", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad &amp; Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks &amp; Caicos", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (US)", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];


function countrycheck(letter) {

  let counrtieswithA = []
  for (let e of country) {
    let firstletter = e[0]
    if (firstletter === letter) {
      counrtieswithA.push(e)
    }
  }
  return counrtieswithA
}

console.log(countrycheck("A"))
```

Comment: Your version returns undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Fixed.

Comment: You should fix the text similarly.

Comment: What's wrong with the test? It returns the correct output.

Comment: The text "You should remove the return statement from your function". You didn't remove it from the function, you just moved it to a different place.

Answer (score 0):

you can user filter

```
var country = ["Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua &amp; Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", "Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "British Virgin Islands", "Brunei", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Congo", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote D Ivoire", "Croatia", "Cruise Ship", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", "Falkland Islands", "Faroe Islands", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Polynesia", "French West Indies", "Gabon", "Gambia", "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guinea Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Isle of Man", "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Laos", "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macedonia", "Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", "Montserrat", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Namibia", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Caledonia", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", "Saint Pierre &amp; Miquelon", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Satellite", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "South Africa", "South Korea", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "St Kitts &amp; Nevis", "St Lucia", "St Vincent", "St. Lucia", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor L'Este", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad &amp; Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Turks &amp; Caicos", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "United Kingdom", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (US)", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"];


function countrycheck(letter) {

  var filter=country.filter(i=>i.toLowerCase().indexOf(letter.toLowerCase()) === 0)
  return filter;
}
console.log(countrycheck('A'))
```